# Regular expression for this alphanumeric string

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = 'SSM1234';
preg_match("SS{2,}\M+\[0-9]", $string);
```

Why does this regex not match my sample `$string`?

i need to check whether the given id is email address or  ssmid.....also check there regular expression

```
    if((!preg_match("/^S{2,}M+[0-9]+$/", $Forgot_field)) || (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $Forgot_field))){

                $result = "Enter a valid SSM ID or Email ID";
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some other sample strings that you want to match. Do all matching strings start with "SSM" or can they have any number of S's or M's (or any letter)?

Answer (score 1):

This should works

```
$string = 'SSM1234'; 
$res = preg_match('/^S{2,}M+[0-9]+$/', $string);
```

You missed the delimiter `/` and your regexp match at least 3 `S`, not 2.

I've added also the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) of match. But it's no mandatory (it depends by your case)

Answer (score 1):

This `SS{2,}` matches the following part of a string `SSS` or `SSS[...]` so at least 3 `S`.

What you need is:

```
/^S{2,}M[0-9]+$/
```

Of course with the missing delimiters, as mentioned abouth.

This regex matches strings like:

```
SSM1
SSSM1
SSSSSSM157453247
SSSM123
```

and so on.

If you need a regex which strictly matches your sample string try:

```
/^S{2}M\d{4}$/
```

This regex matches exactly `{2}` times a `S`, a `M` and then `{4}` times a digit (`\d`).